# Why does this variable cause an “is not a function” error?

Tags: javascript

```
 window.onload = raknaUtMedelvarde;

function raknaUtMedelvarde(){

    var tabell = document.getElementById("temperaturtabell");
    var rader = tabell.getElementsByTagName("tr");

    for (var i = 0; i < rader.length; i++){
        var tabellcell = rader[i].getElementById("td");
       //räkna ut medelvärde
        var medel = medelVarde(tabellcell);

        var medelText = document.createTextNode(medel);
        var medelElement = tabellcell[tabellcell.length - 1];
        medelElement.appendChild(medelText);


    }
}

function medelVarde(celler){
    var summa = 0;
    for (var i = 1; i < celler.length - 1; i++){

         var nuvarandeVarde = celler[i].firstChild.nodeValue;
         summa = summa + parseInt(nuvarandeVarde);
    }
    return summa / 5;
```

According to the **error-console** on Firefox this variable "tabellcell: var tabellcell = rader[i].getElementById("td");" is not a function? uhn?

Comment: Does `medelVarde()` expect a function as argument?

Comment: You should post your medelVarde() function too.

Comment: @ Marcel yes I'm, My tables has 6 cells...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error is on that line

```
 var tabellcell = rader[i].getElementById("td")
```

Replacing getElementById with getElementsByTagName

```
  var tabellcell = rader[i].getElementsByTagName("td")
```

Comment: @ Marwan hihi! rightON!!!!!!  it was: getElementsByTagName("td")
 ^_^) thanks very much!!

Comment: just please dont forget to mark my answer as a correct one if it was useful to you 

with My Regard :)

Comment: there is a correct sign on the left side of my answer just click on it and all be done :) and also you can use the up arrow beside my answer too :)

Answer (score 3):

you cannot use

`rader[i].getElementById("td");`

getElementById is a method of document object. rader variable holds some other objects (element objects) I assume.

element objects only have `getElementsByTagName` and `getElementsByClassName` you can use them.

Comment: I thought the same, but this is not the reason for that error: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/VPq8y/1/

Comment: **Correction:** No, it is indeed the reason. I forgot to deselect Mootools as library and it seems to add a `getElementById` function to the elements. NVM!

Comment: @MarcelKorpel: No... but I have an excuse: Yesterday was my birthday and I'm still a bit tired :D ;) Maybe I should stop writing nonesense now and start cleaning... it's better for everyone I suppose :)